Kafka streams application reset to a particular offset for new consumer group
I am a kafka stream application containing one input and one output topic. I do not have any stateful processing. I have a usecase where when the application id (aka consumer group) is newly created, I want to reset the offsets to a particular point (say shift by 100, or consume all the data produced since yesterday).
I did follow below article and tried shifting the offsets by 3. It did shift by 3 and the lag was produced still I was not able to process them. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Note : I had to manually reset the offset to latest and then shifted them by 3.
Reference : https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application
command ran : kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --bootstrap-servers <b1,b2> --application-id  --input-topics  --config-file  --shift-by -3
